# How do I join on two columns in the hibernate mapping file using the <join> tag?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

I need to map a single class to two tables (both with multiple columns primary key). Let's say TABLE1 has id1, id2, id3 and TABLE2 has id1, id2 as primary keys. Now when writing the mapping file I would do something like the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="beans">
  <class name="TABLE1Class" table="TABLE1">
    <composite-id name="table1PK" class="TABLE1PKClass">
        <key-many-to-one name="id1" class="ID1Class" column="id1"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="id2" class="ID2Class" column="id2"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="id3" class="ID3Class" column="id3"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="someProperty" type="integer" not-null="true" column="x"/>
    <join table="TABLE2">
        <key column="id1" />
        <!-- <key column="id2"/> The join tag accepts only one key tag!!! 
How do I map the second key??? -->
        <property name="propertyFromTable2" type="float" not-null="true"/>
    </join>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**As you can see the join tag accepts only one key tag! How do I map the second Id?**

Answer (score 2):

`<key>` may contain multiple `<column>` elements:

```
<key>
    <column name = "id1" />
    <column name = "id2" />
    <column name = "id3" />
</key>
```

Comment: Hi axtavt, I followed your instructions and this solved the problem with the multiplicity, but another exception occurred since I have two ids in TABLE2 (id1,id2): "org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK:TABLE2 [id1,id2])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (TABLE1 [id3])".

Comment: I tried providing a dummy column as described here https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2229088&sid=a709d63dc318557b72b76366b8d7b804 (<column name="id3" default="1"/>), but I got: "org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK:TABLE2 [id1,id2,id3])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (TABLE1 [id3])". Any suggestion?

Comment: @despot Hi, it's been a long time, have yous solved this issue? If so, can you please tell how? Having just the same trouble now:)